# Shell not showing in SWT

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I can't get my Shell to show when using SWT. I had it working when I run the code as a separate thread. However, I need it on the SWT Display Thread - after moving to the SWT Display Thread it fails to show.

Here is my code:

```
public class TestSetup extends Canvas {

    private Shell shell;

    public void voiceInitialise() {
        Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initializeComponents();
                runEventLoop();
            }
        });
    }

    public void initializeComponents() {
        shell = SWT_AWT.new_Shell(new Display(), this);
    }

    public void runEventLoop() {
        Thread curThread = Thread.currentThread();
        curThread.setName(curThread.getName() + " SWT Dispatch");
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        testSetup();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    public void testSetup() {
        shell.setText("Title");
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
        shell.setSize(530, 320);
        shell.setLayout(layout);
        shell.open();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestSetup t = new TestSetup();
        t.voiceInitialise();
    }
}
```

It just gives me this exception: "Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access"

If anyone knows how to resolve please let me know.

Comment: 1. Post the stack trace of the exception. 2. Why are you using `SWT_AWT`? Avoid it unless you actually need it. I don't see anything particularly suspicious other than that.

Comment: This seems like overkill. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

As GGrec pointed out your code is quite an overkill.

From your code I assume you are trying to embed SWT into AWT, so your class should rather look like the following:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SWTEmbeddedExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //AWT frame comes here
        Frame frame = new Frame("My AWT Application");
        Canvas parentCanvas = new Canvas();
        frame.add(parentCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        //SWT_AWT bridge
        final Display display = Display.getDefault();
        final Shell shell = SWT_AWT.new_Shell(display, parentCanvas);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

        //SWT label with text and red background
        Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("My embedded SWT label");
        label.setBackground(new Color(display, new RGB(255, 0, 0)));

        //AWT frame config goes here
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                e.getWindow().dispose();
                //optionally also dispose display
            }
        });
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //ReadAndDispatch display as long as frame is displayed
        while (frame.isDisplayable()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```